# Crashlytics detected a missing dSYM for version

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, dsym

Inconsistently I will receive an email from Firebase stating `Crashlytics detected a missing dSYM for version x.x.x`

However nothing in the build process has changed. I use GitHub actions to create the build.

All of my release targets have the `Debug Information Format` set to `DWARF with dSYM File`

So I am not sure if this is something I can fix as it doesn't happen every time.

Any thoughts on where to look or try next?

Comment: did you find solution?? I faced the same problem as you

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @SantosRamón Posted my solution

Comment: @ga-yo Posted my solution

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue. During a previous merge, we got rid of our Firebase script that would upload the DSYM - https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?platform=ios#set-up-dsym-uploading